# CodeIgniter Cart unable to hold more than 10 items

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm testing adding items to the shopping cart like this:

```
$item = $this->model->getSingleItem();

for($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++) {
    $this->cart->insert(array(
            'id' => $item->id++,
            'qty' => 1,
            'price' => 1,
            'name' => $item->title
        ));
}
```

However, the above loop only adds 10 items to the shopping cart. Even if I modify the loop above to run 20 times, I still get only 10 items in the cart. Is this a known bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Doing `echo count($this->cart->contents());` always shows a count of 10 or less. Never more.

I'm using CI 2.1.2. If someone can confirm they don't face this issue in a previous version, perhaps I can use the cart class from an older version of CI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. The reason I was unable to store more than 10 items is because I was hitting the limit on cookie size (CI sessions are stored as cookies). I changed my config to use databases for sessions, and this issue went away.

Comment: How did you do that? pls explain. I am facing the same issue

Comment: The cart stores data in session, and CI session uses cookies by default. You need to switch sessions to use database which is documented here: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver